# Do almost half of Londoners think that cutting immigration would help London's housing crisis?

Tags: politics, united-kingdom, immigration

As a Christmas present on the 25th I just got a leaflet from UKIP in my post stating that

> 44% of Londoners say that cutting EU immigration would help solve the
>   London housing crisis.

There are no references on the leaflet except for a NationBuilder based website, where you have to register (and according to the comments even after that they need to verify you and won't get access).

[image: Leaflet]

I tried to search for this claim but couldn't find any references where it originates from, or any additional information, like who they actually consider Londoner.

Is this claim still true?

Comment: As im finding those number nowhere as well i tried to create a fake account for that page. Turns out you need to get whitelisted for that page, not even a (fake) UKIP Account can access it. Submitted my account details to [bugmenot.com](http://bugmenot.com/view/your-view.eu).